# Similar Keras models produce different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

What is the difference between these two models? Because each produce different results consistently.

**Model 1**

```
Input = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9,activation='linear')
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='relu')
hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='relu')
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')

model = tf.keras.Sequential([Input, Dropout(0.2), hidden, Dropout(0.2), hidden2, output])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
```

**Model 2**

```
hidden_units1 = 9
hidden_units2 = 10
hidden_units3 = 10

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  Dense(hidden_units1, activation='linear'),
  Dropout(0.2),
  Dense(hidden_units2, activation='relu'),
  Dropout(0.2),
  Dense(hidden_units3, activation='relu'),
  Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
```

Comment: They produce different predictions due to random weight initialization.

Comment: Both examples create the same network _architecture_.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, at first i also thought that it might just be random weight initialization but after several trials, Model 2 consistently performs better than Model 1 by a lot. where the mean absolute error of model 2 floats at about 0.5-1.0, the mean absolute error of model 1 is always over 5.

Comment: please provide more context, Dr.Snoopy and jkr are right, sot you are doing something else that leads to this difference

Comment: If you are training your models, could you add your model.fit() statements to the sample code please? I've run both on a simple regression, and they perform just the same as each other.

Comment: I think you are seeing patterns in random data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Models are the same, so it would be better to init one of these models and derive its weights by get_weights(), then train that model, and after that init the next model and set its weights by the wights of the previous model with set_weights(weights), it's the closest way to make the same models training performance the same.